# cmake compile fails for project synergy-through-usb on windows

Tags: c++, windows, git, cmake

I am trying to build the following c++ project from github on windows 64bit system:
[synergy-through-usb](https://github.com/iHateInventNames/synergy-through-usb).

It says I need to use cmake, so I have installed cmake latest version.

I then downloaded and unzipped the source code.

Then I ran `cmake .` in the folder, but I got the following error:

```
C:\local\projects\synergy-usb\synergy-through-usb-master>cmake .
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/arch
   used as include directory in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/net
LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY
    linked by target "arch" in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/arch

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am not familiar with cmake and also the links to the instructions / guide for this git repo seem to be removed:

- http://synergy-project.org/projects/synergy/wiki/Readme/?hl=pm
- http://synergy-project.org/projects/synergy/wiki/Compiling/?hl=pm

Can anyone help me compile this - i.e. suggest what I need to do to get around these errors? or has anyone tried to use this project?

Comment: The message seems to indicate that you are at least missing libusb. I cannot answer yet since more errors might appear...

Comment: @SirDarius thanks, hmm.... ok, I know how to install that on linux... but on windows, how do you resolve that?

Comment: I've never used it before, but I guess you can try to find a binary distribution and edit CMake variables in the cache to point at the correct locations.

Comment: @SirDarius Oh, no, I meant how do you get libusb.... I am looking around now it does not look so simple :(

Comment: I googled and find a download link for the binary distribution on Sourceforge.There are binaries for mingw and MSVC compilers in there.

Comment: @SirDarius ok, I downloaded mingw and added it to my path so that I could then attept to build libusb from sourceforge... but it now it complains about  `-mno-cygwin` not being recognised parameter, and this is just to try to build libusb, seem to be getting further from the original issue. I could not see an actual binary (pre compiled) for libusb, did you find one?

Comment: I believe I already stated so in a previous comment.

Comment: @SirDarius ok... I modify my question: can you post the link?, as I mentioned I could not see a pre-compiled version... there is plenty of source code which I really don't want to have to build : (